# Не получается параллельно запустить gitlab + nginx

Tags: nginx, gitlab

Установил на чистую Ubuntu 18.10 nginx, gitlab.
Gitlab виден на 80 порту, хотя указан external_url. И nginx не запускается, с ошибкой, что порт используется. 
Убиваем гитлаб, nginx запускается нормально. 
Как их правильно подружить?

Comment: Уточните, что в итоге надо: запустить их на разных портах, спрятать гитлаб за нджинкс (реверс-прокси), etc.

Comment: У меня не получалось скинуть gitlab с 80 порта. Уже получилось и nginx ом перекинул реверс прокси на нужный домен на этот порт.